# Is there a way to copy files using SAS EG in PCFILES server?

Tags: sas

I am using SAS EG with UNIX system. However, there are some instances when I need to use MS Access lookup tables, so I asked our admin if there was a solution. They installed a PCFiles server. I am not 100% sure how it works but I am now easily able to create a library off of any MS Access database like this:

```
libname ac PCFILES path="D:\dde\actuarial\mbrsop\2018_07/member_lookups.mdb" server=cncpwsasa1027 port=9622;
```

At the beginning of each month I need to create bunch of new folders in UNIX and copy bunch of files from previous month's folder to new folder. For UNIX files and folders I use code like this:

```
%sysexec cd /utils/gpfs0/files/warehouse/corp/actuarial_rpt/mbrsop/data;
%sysexec mkdir &new_month.;
%sysexec cp /utils/gpfs0/files/projects/corp/actuarial_rpt/membership/pgm/&old_month./variables.sas
    /utils/gpfs0/files/projects/corp/actuarial_rpt/membership/pgm/&new_month./variables.sas;
```

Is there a way to create a folder in the PCFILES server in a similar way as above? Using the code below obviously does not work.

```
%sysexec cd D:\dde\actuarial\mbrsop;
%sysexec mkdir &new_month.;
%sysexec cp D:\dde\actuarial\mbrsop\&old_month./member_lookups.accdb D:\dde\actuarial\mbrsop\&new_month./member_lookups.accdb;
```

How to get SAS EG to understand I want to create the folder and copy files in PCFILES server and not in UNIX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send general operating system commands to a PCFILES server.

Ask your system team to schedule a batch job on the Windows machine that is being used to run the PCFILES server to run those commands for you.

Comment: Is there any other way? Using something like this: data _null_;
    newmth = dcreate("&copyTo.", "&root.\");
run;

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation-- SAS EG on Unix, PC Files Server, store and work with many files on Windows.
I have used a different tool (VBScript - which can natively run on Windows; R; Python; others) to create folder structures in advance of them being needed, and then scheduled with Windows Task Scheduler. I can provide more details if you think that would work.